# Redundant references vs. historical data

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, relational-database

I have a domain model in which each line item is associated with a product.  The product has a list of options.  Each option is either required or optional.  The user can include an optional option which will add it to the line item's selections list.

In order to avoid redundancy, my first thought was to exclude required options from the line item's selections list.  There are a lot of required options, so including them for every line item would lead to a bloated database.

The problem is that the products can potentially change over time.  Options that were once required could become optional, and visa-versa.  And entirely new options may be added to the product.  This creates a problem with my initial idea, since the meaning of line items' selection lists would depend on a product's options at the time of the order.

So what should I do?

1. If I also include required options in the line item's selection lists, then the model is simple.  I'd have a snapshot of the options that were included with the product.  But then I've also got a lot of bloat in the database since references to required options will be repeated for every line item.  Is this something I should be worried about or will SQL Server do some kind of behind-the-scenes compression?
2. Should I pursue my original idea of excluding required options from the line item's selection lists?  Then I would need to keep some historical data regarding changes to the products.  That way I could recreate the product and its options as they existed at the time of the order.  Sounds possible but more complicated than the first option.  I worry it would take more CPU cycles but that would be okay if its for old orders which won't be opened very often.  I've never had to do this myself before, but maybe it wouldn't be so hard.  If this is the approach you recommend, please provide some pointers to design patterns, etc. to help me get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the first option if there's any chance that your list of required options will change in the future.  If you don't store those options with each line item in the database, then you have to keep track of which options were required on which dates, and join them separately.  This will needlessly complicate your join logic.

As for bloating your database, I don't think this will be as bad as you might think.  It sounds like you probably already have join tables for `ProductOptions` and `LineItemOptions` that just contains product keys and option keys.  This latter table should be the only one that ends up having more records based on your first design choice.  Since it only contains keys, its records are not going to take up a lot more memory, and joining on it will be really fast anyway.